# This message is flooding my syslog, how to find where it comes from?

Tags: networking

When I run `dmesg` this comes up every second or so:

```
[22661.447946] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=ee:54:32:37:94:5f:f0:4b:3a:4f:80:30:08:00 SRC=35.162.106.154 DST=104.248.41.4 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=37 ID=52549 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=25 DPT=50616 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0
```

How can I trace what is causing this message?

Comment: It is the annoying ufw logging. You can turn it off. It is also possible to configure ufw to use a different log channel, thus it won't contaminate dmesg, but it is very tricky (might require even a little ufw patch).

Comment: FWIW if you're unfamiliar with UFW, you should probably not have your system connected directly to the internet.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The existing answer is correct in its technical analysis of the firewall log entry, but it's missing one point that makes the conclusion incorrect.  The packet

- Is a `RST` (reset) packet
- from `SRC=35.162.106.154`
- to your host at `DST=104.248.41.4`
- via `TCP`
- from his port `SPT=25`
- to your port `DPT=50616`
- and has been `BLOCK`ed by UFW.

Port 25 (the source port) is commonly used for email.  Port 50616 is in the [ephemeral port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port) range, meaning there's no consistent user for this port.  A TCP "reset" packet can be sent in response to a number of unexpected situations, such as data arriving after a connection has been closed, or data being sent without first establishing a connection.

`35.162.106.154` reverse-resolves to `cxr.mx.a.cloudfilter.net`, a domain used by the CloudMark email filtering service.

Your computer, or someone pretending to be your computer, is sending data to one of CloudMark's servers.  The data is arriving unexpectedly, and the server is responding with a `RST` to ask the sending computer to stop.  Given that the firewall is dropping the `RST` rather than passing it through to some application, the data that's causing the `RST` to be sent isn't coming from your computer.  Instead, you're probably seeing backscatter from a denial-of-service attack, where the attacker is sending out floods of packets with forged "from" addresses in an attempt to knock CloudMark's mail servers offline (perhaps to make spamming more effective).

Comment: +1 for the great analysis! I had no idea...

Answer (score 15):

The messages stems from [*UFW*](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/ufw.8.html), the "uncomplicated firewall" and it tells you that someone

- from `SRC=35.162.106.154`
- tried to connect to your host at `DST=104.248.41.4`
- via `TCP`
- from their port `SPT=25`
- to your port `DPT=50616`
- and that UFW has successfully `BLOCK`ed that attempt.

According to [this site](https://abongo.com/investigate/35.162.106.154/host) 
the source address 35.162.106.154 is some Amazon machine (probably an AWS).
According to [this site](http://www.adminsub.net/tcp-udp-port-finder/50616)
the port 50616 may be used for *Xsan Filesystem Access*.

So it's an attempt from IP=35.162.106.154 to access your files. Quite normal
and nothing to be really worried about because that's what firewalls are for:
rejecting such attempts.

Comment: It seems the attempted connection is from an amazon account, port 25 is a mail port should I report this or just ignore it? Spamming my logs

Comment: @peterretief you can block it at your router; then you won't see it. But it might be wise to report this to your ISP.

Comment: Actually it says „RST“ not „SYN“ so it is a denied outgoing SMTP attempt packet which was filtered out.

Comment: The other answer seems more likely to be correct to me.

Comment: @Barmar Indeed, and very kindly put. That one should be the accepted answer.